# Angular JS script throwing $http:baddata when trying to receive response from Spring Boot controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

After sending POST request, I am able to receive response from my Spring Controller (I can see that in network tab like below) but when AngularJS tries to process it I am getting '$http:baddata' error console. Please help.

Below is error in chrome developer tools console.

> angular.js:14800 Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$http/baddata?p0=name%3D123%20from%20service&p1=%7B%7D
>
> ```
> at angular.js:88
> at uc (angular.js:11392)
> at angular.js:11485
> at r (angular.js:408)
> at yd (angular.js:11484)
> at g (angular.js:12326)
> at angular.js:17169
> at m.$digest (angular.js:18352)
> at m.$apply (angular.js:18649)
> at l (angular.js:12627) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
> ```

[image]

Below is my html and script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MY SERVICE</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="testController">
  <p>AIRPORT CODE: <input type="text" name="airportCode" ng-model="airportCode" required /></p>
  <button ng-click="SendData()">REQUEST</button> 

</div>
```

```js
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);

testApp.controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.SendData = function(){

  var reqData = $.param({

  name: $scope.airportCode

  });  

  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/employees',
        data: reqData

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("success" + response.data);
    });
};

});
```

Below is my Spring Boot controller.

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(value = "/employees")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllEmployeesJSON() 
    {
        return "hi what up";
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/employees")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createEmployee(@RequestBody String  name) 
    {      
        System.out.println( "This is from client: "+ name);
        return name + " from service";
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a server-side problem, the response that is coming from the server, is not coming in JSON format, while it's expecting it in a JSON format,
Based on your content-type, you might want to implement [your own response transformer per request basis](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request)

Comment: can you try changing your controller to this ?  `@PostMapping(value = "/employees", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`